# how to use range query using mongodb 3.2

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using mongodb 3.2 version.I'm trying to use the following query for the below dataset.But I'm unable to fetch the records due to the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at com.mongodb.QueryResultIterator.next(QueryResultIterator.java:103)
```

My dataset:

```
BasicDBObject obj3 = new BasicDBObject();
obj3.put("name", "Dhoni");
obj3.put("location", "Ranchi");
obj3.put("Profession", "Cricketer");
obj3.put("number", 3);

BasicDBObject obj4 = new BasicDBObject();
obj4.put("name", "Sakshi");
obj4.put("location", "Ranchi");
obj4.put("Profession", "HtlMgmt");
obj4.put("number", 4);

BasicDBObject obj5 = new BasicDBObject();
obj5.put("name", "Ziva");
obj5.put("location", "Ranchi");
obj5.put("Profession", "Player");
obj5.put("number", 5);
```

My query:

```
BasicDBObject gtquery = new BasicDBObject();
        gtquery.put("number",new BasicDBObject("$gt",3).append("$lt",5));

        DBCursor cursor4 = col.find(gtquery);
        while(cursor4.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }
```

Can anyone please help me out regarding this exception...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the range, say 3 < number < 5, change your query to:

```
BasicDBObject gtquery = new BasicDBObject("number", 
    new BasicDBObject("$gt", 3).append("$lt", 5)
);

DBCursor cur = col.find(gtquery);
try {
    while (cur.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(cur.next());
    }
} finally {
    cur.close();
}
```

Comment: Hi chridam,I'm facing an error after editing the code to the above mentioned format.Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoException: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $lt

Comment: @dev777 There was a typo in the code - removed an extra bracket in the query, should work now.

Comment: Hi chridam,can u please refer this url :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623703/how-to-fetch-the-record-from-mongodb-using-id-field-in-java