# How to fetch the record from mongodb using _id field and display the fetched record in the console using java

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to retrieve the record from mongodb using "_id" field. But I'm getting null as output.

My code:

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
        DB db = mongo.getDB("sample");
        DBCollection col = db.getCollection("matching");

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
            query.put("_id", new ObjectId("56cec592fe3fc16f6b564761"));
            DBObject dbObj = col.findOne(query);
            System.out.println(dbObj); //getting output as null
```

My record in mongodb :

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56cec592fe3fc16f6b564761"),
        "name" : "vishal",
        "location" : "Delhi",
        "Profession" : "SE",
        "number" : 2
}
```

Comment: just check whether the db name and collection name is correct. Even case is matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could import `org.bson.types.ObjectId` that you can wrap the `id` with and use it in your query as

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
...

MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
DB db = mongo.getDB("sample");
DBCollection col = db.getCollection("matching");
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("_id", new ObjectId("56cec592fe3fc16f6b564761"));
DBObject dbObj = col.findOne(query);
```

Comment: How to print that dbObj.I'm using sysout to print dbObj but I'm getting null as output.I had used the same code but still facing this issue ...

Comment: Your question is implying something different: here you want to `print` but your question implies `fetch`, which is which?

Comment: Yes,I'm trying to fetch the record in the dbObj and trying to display the fetched object in the console

Comment: Then please update your question accordingly, you've left out how you are printing the result part.

Comment: I'm able to retrieve the dbObj using sysout.Thanks a lot for ur help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            DBObject dbObj = col.findOne(new ObjectId("56cec592fe3fc16f6b564761"));
```

Comment: still I'm getting output as null

Comment: Please provide more than just code. How is this change supposed to address the question?